# In SilkTest is it possible for one window to inherit from another

Tags: silktest

I have a window Win1 - it has multiple associated objects and methods.
I want to create window Win2 which is exact replica of Win1 but different in some aspects.

Is it possible to link the two by, say, inheriting one from another.

Something like window

```
WPFWindow Win2_Win1WithSomeDifferences 
    inherits Win1
    //some more objects
    //additional code goes here
```

Kindly let me know of options.

Using Silktest 13.5.

Comment: What Silk Test client and language are you using?

Comment: As mentioned in the question using Silktest 13.5, 4Test as language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using

```
winclass Win2_Win1WithSomeDifferences : Win1
```